# An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, uri

i keep getting this error every time i run the application, the uri is generated but when i try to send a toast notification by clicking a button on an aspn webpage the program crashes and displays that error(An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code) here is my thread of code:[crashes on HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(channelURI);line ]

```
public string SendNotification(string message)
        {
            string channelURI = "PUT_YOUR_CHANNEL_URI_HERE";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(channelURI);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "2");
            request.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");

            string notificationData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
           "<wp:Toast>" +
              "<wp:Text1>WP7 TOAST</wp:Text1>" +
              "<wp:Text2>" + message + "</wp:Text2>" +
           "</wp:Toast>" +
        "</wp:Notification>";

            byte[] contents = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(notificationData);

            request.ContentLength = contents.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);
            }

            string notificationStatus;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
            }

            return notificationStatus;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You copied the sample with the `"PUT_YOUR_CHANNEL_URI_HERE"` value as it is. You will need to provide a real channel URI since this one is malformed and thus throws the `UriFormatException`.

Comment: i changed that and gave it a proper channel name but its still  not working

Comment: Can you show the code you *do* use and detail the exception you get? Without that any help would be guessing out.